# How to mock a custom hook inside of a React component you want to test?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks

If you have a React component that calls a custom hook that fetches data, what is the best way to mock that internal custom hook result when testing the React component? I see 2 main approaches:

1) Jest.mock the custom hook. This seems to be the most recommended approach, but it seems like it requires the test to have more knowledge of internal implementation details and what it might need to mock than what the props interface of the component might suggest (assuming use of prop-types or TypeScript)

2) Use a dependency injection approach. Declare the hook as a prop, but default it to the real hook so you don't have to set it everywhere you render the component, but allow overriding with a mock for tests. Here is a contrived codesandbox example with a test that mocks a custom hook:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dependency-inject-custom-hook-for-testing-mjqlf?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js

2 requires more typing, but seems easier to work with for testing. However, tests already have to have knowledge of internal implementation details of component to test any conditional logic for rendered output, so maybe that's not important and 1 is the best approach. Is 1 the way to go? What tradeoffs do you see? Am I missing another approach altogether?

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing. I was using recompose for about a year before React Hooks was introduced and LOVED what it did for decoupling and easy unit testing. Andrew Clark (recompose) also worked on React Hooks and recommends using it over recompose, but I have yet to see decent examples that illustrate the same ability to decouple. Does anyone have any decent examples of how to approach hooks in the same way that recompose approach HoCs?

Comment: So much this @WillSchoenberger!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a few months old, but if you haven't found a good solution, I wrote a package that might help. I went through a similar thought process, including "what if I inject the hooks into the component?" Things got weird.

I basically wanted a connecter to avoid an extra wrapper for presentational components just to test them.

I came up with `react-hooks-compose`, which lets you keep your hooks and your presenters separate, and test them individually or together: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hooks-compose

```js
export const useFetch = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData('some-url') // <-- Fetches data on mount
      .then(res => setUser(res.data));
  }, []);

  return {user};
}

// composeHooks passes the values from your hooks as props
export const UserPresenter = ({user}) => {
  return <div>You fetched data for: {user.name}</div>;
}

export default composeHooks({ useFetch })(DataPresenter);
```

Now you don't have to mock the hook, you can just test the presenter with a prop:

```js
it('presents user', () => {
  const { queryByText } = render(<UserPresenter user={{name: 'Mary'}} />); // <-- Named export
  expect(queryByText('Mary')).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Or, you have the option of a higher-level integration test:

```js
it('fetches data', () => {
  fetchData.mockResolvedValue('Mary');
  const { queryByText } = render(<UserWithData />); // <-- Default export
  expect(queryByText('Mary')).toBeFalsy();
  return wait(() => {
    expect(queryByText('Mary')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

You can even unit test the hook if you like.

Comment: Yep, came across that package awhile ago and forgot to update this question. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 15):

To mock your custom hook using jest.

```
import * as useCustomHook from '../hooks/useCustomHooks'

const spy = jest.spyOn(useCustomHook, 'default')
spy.mockReturnValue({
name: 'test'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you mock the underlying method that makes the api call instead?

For example, if you're retrieving data with `fetch()`, you mock that instead. That way you can define custom response for that call, which will make testing the hook itself easy.

Comment: Doing this is no longer a unit test. Your component shouldn't care about the implementation detail of how data is retrieved; that's the job of the hook function. If you later decide to change the hook's implementation, you have to refactor all of the tests that consume it. This can also spiral out of control. Imagine if the hook gets the data it passes to the api from another hook that reads from `useContext`.

Comment: @EricHaynes I know this is old, but how is the alternative "still" a unit test? Even if you're just mocking the hook itself, it's still an external dependency being invoked by the body of your component, and the only way you could know about this is by looking at the implementation details of that component. I'm not saying mocking fetch is better, just clarifying when something is or isn't a unit test and wondering when it matters

Comment: The hook is the external dependency of the component. `fetch` is the external dependency of the external dependency. The further out the "chain" you make your mocks, the more brittle the test suite becomes, because if you change the hook, you have to update the test for the component. This can snowball rather easily, leaving you with a system where small changes result in updating a bunch of tests, ruining their efficacy, IMO. The component shouldn't really care whether the data comes from an api, a websocket, or a carrier pigeon, so a test specifically for the component shouldn't either.

Answer (score 0):

With mocking hook itself you never know if real one works well all together with your component.

With passing hook as a prop it would be really hard to make hooks communicate with each other. E.g. when you need your custom hook to call setter from the same component `useState`. You would need to extend custom hook with more and more parameters.

3. You may mock external API call - I mean mocking `fetch` or `XHR`. It still needs to know some implementation details - the fact you're running HTTP request - but there are less things your test should know about.

Comment: "With passing hook as a prop it would be really hard to make hooks communicate with each other." How is that different from importing the hook from a module? You still can't use .e.g `useState` setter if you import, can you? Unless you pass it as a parameter to the hook. Which you can also do if you inject the hook