# RTL: Mock a custom React hook only for selected unit tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a custom hook called `useInitialSetup` that returns a key-value dictionary object.
It's being consumed in App.tsx.

In App.test.tsx, I have a suite of unit tests written using Jest and React Testing Library.

**Is it possible to mock `useInitialSetup` in only a selection of unit tests, but not all?**

Here's what I have tried in App.test.tsx:

```
jest.mock('../../hooks/useInitialSetup', () => {
  return jest.fn(() => ({
    loading: mockLoading,
    suspendedTrial: mockSuspendedTrial,
    maxTrials: mockMaxTrials,
    reachedMaxTrials: mockReachedMaxTrials,
  }));
});

it('Unit test that uses a mocked version of useInitialSetup', () => {
  render(<App/>)
  ...
})

it('Unit test that uses the real implementation of useInitialSetup', () => {
  jest.dontMock('../../hooks/useInitialSetup')
  render(<App/>)
  ...
})
```

Unit test #2 still uses the mocked version of `useInitialSetup`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest Mock module per test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66326501/1870780)

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks for posting that link. I didn't quite go with that solution. This was a closer match to what I was looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62138485/1930938

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing. This lets me mock the output of my `useInitialSetup` custom hook for this one selected unit test. Any subsequent unit tests will use the default implementation of this hook.

```
import * as useInitialSetup from '../../hooks/useInitialSetup';

it('Test', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(useInitialSetup, 'default');
  spy.mockReturnValue({
    loading: false,
    reachedMaxTrials: true,
    errorCheckingCanCreateInstance: false,
    errorFetchingUser: false,

    // @ts-ignore
    suspendedTrial: mockSuspendedTrial,
    resetChecks: () => {},
    maxTrials: 1,
  });

  render(setupComponent());
  expect(true).toBe(true) // or whatever assertion you want
  spy.mockRestore();
})
```